# How can I integrate Visual Leak Detector with TeamCity?

Tags: visual-c++, teamcity, visual-leak-detector

Can I integrate Visual Leak Detector with TeamCity? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Parse its leak reports.

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /B *_memLeak.txt') DO (
  findstr "/C:No memory leaks detected." "%%F"
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      echo ##teamcity[buildProblem description='Leaks in %%~nxF']
  )
)
```